# ExtJs: How to validate editible Grid and prevent empty cells

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I need to validate a grid using [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/02/extjs-grid-validation-error-qtip.html) link. But I can't use **getByCellPosition** function and it returns false because of its input parameters **{row: idx, column: i}** .

How can I get cell from the grid and call this function?

```
store = grid.getStore();
view = grid.getView();
error = false;
columnLength = grid.columns.length;

    store.each(function(record,idx){
     for (var i = 0; i < columnLength; i++) {
      cell = view.getCellByPosition({row: idx, column: i});
      cell.removeCls("x-form-invalid-field");
      cell.set({'data-errorqtip': ''});
      fieldName = grid.columns[i].dataIndex;
      if (fieldName === 'WHATEVER') {
       //Do your validation here
       if(failed) {
        cell.addCls("x-form-invalid-field");
        cell.set({'data-errorqtip': 'Your error message qtip'});
        error = true;
       }
        }
     }  
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using 'renderer' is easy and efficient way. If its suitable with your code, you can try this:         https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tl3

```
var validRenderer = function (val, meta, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            if (val == isNotValid) {
                meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=" '+val+' is not right person"';
                meta.style = "background-color:red;"; 
            }
            return val;
        }



        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store1,
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    renderer: validRenderer
                }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
```

Comment: thanks mate. the only problem is that I want to prevent the form from being saved. how can I do it here?

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tl3  There are several solutions. You can check the records whether are valid before save (before button click or if you use remote store, you can use beforesync listener. It depends how to save the records). Btw I added example solution to the fiddle